# DHCP ivp6 vs DHCP ipv4 router config (cisco)

Tags: cisco, router, ipv4, dhcp, ipv6

When setting up a router as dchp server in ipv4, we specify a pool under which we give the network and the default-gateway and that's it:
[image]

However in ipv6 stateless dhcp , we create the pool then refer it in A PARTICULAR INTERFACE  
[image]

Why can't we do something for all the interfaces like in the ipv4 case ?

Comment: Please post your configurations as plain preformatted text using `{` and `}`.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Cisco, but doing DHCPv4 with one subnet on multiple LANs is not a great idea either. Especially if machines need to reach each other within the subnet.

Comment: Because v4 and v6 are totally different things, that work in totally different ways. Stateless DHCPv6 doesn't hand out addresses, just "other" information. (yes, DHCP in IPv6 was a bolt-on afterthought. SLAAC is The One True Way(tm), except the nuts ignored all the other things a host needs to function)

Comment: Please, never use images for text. Edit your question to remove the images and simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).